# output results from 2 mySQLtables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my mySQL database `csm` and `csmproducts`.

Table csm stores the customer info and table csmproducts stores the products they ordered.

"Order_ID" is the common variable in both tables.

I have written a query which pulls data from both tables.

My query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT c.*, p.Product_SKU from csm c, csmproducts p where c.Order_ID = p.Order_ID and c.Order_Status='Awaiting Fulfillment' group by Order_ID order by Order_ID DESC LIMIT $startrow, 50";
 $numresults=mysql_query($query);
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);
}
```

The trouble I am having is that if one order (hence one Order_ID) has multiple products in it , only the first product is showing.

What do I need to do so that where `{$row['Product_SKU']}` gives me only the first product for a particular `Order_ID`, that I am able to pull all the `Product_SKUs` for that particular `Order_ID`?

For example `Order_ID 5558` has 3 products associated with it (DSC-3433, ASD-6454, UFY-7383)

Currently the output looks like this (showing just the first item the customer orderd)

```
Order ID: 5558                     
Product SKU: DSC3433
```

I would like to see it like this:

```
Order ID: 5558
Product SKU: DSC-3433, ASD-6454, UFY-7383
```

That is: all 3 products associated with that `Order_ID` to be shown.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

USE [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
[with exlplanation](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

Comment: Sorry, I would need more help than that.

Comment: did u try to use `GROUP_CONCAT`??